# "string index out of range" error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner of Python and I am stuck with "string index out of range" error.

I have a list of company_post_code which looks like this: ['AB31 4DB', 'PO12 1LY', 'PO12 1LY', 'TA2 6BJ', 'B29 6BD', ...] (and also the corresponding company names). And I have another list of English_post_code which looks like this: ['AL', 'B', 'BA', 'BB', 'BD', 'BH', 'BL', 'BN', ...].

I am attempting to find the companies in England by comparing their first one/two postcodes with English postcodes. I have no clue why this code doesn't work.

[image: My code is the following:]

Comment: Hi @ruijiang, could you please post your code instead of a snapshot of it?

Comment: Apparently some of the strings in `company_post_code` has less than 2 characters, causing the attempt to get the character at index 1 to raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! There are some missing data in the list of company_post_code. That's why this code doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing the string on which this fails. Try temporarily wraping the code in a `try..except` block to isolate the error. Note that iterating over an index is unnecessary and frowned upon by most pythonites:

```
for the_code, the_name in zip(company_post_code, company_name):
    try:
        if (the_code[1].isdigit() ...
            company_in_England.append(the_name)
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        print('|{}|'.format(the_code))
        raise e
```

I've put vertical bars in the `print` statement to make it more obvious if there are whitespace characters in the offending string.

Comment: You should reraise the exception.

Comment: Correct, @Bruno, so I've edited the code. However, this `try...except` block should not remain in the code, it's a strictly temporary diagnostic.

Comment: This should be `raise`, not `raise e`, else you loose the original traceback.

Comment: Correct again, **bruno**. Also, variable names should be meaningful, and one should never catch generic Exception objects. Instead, we should have `except IndexError index_err:` and leave everything else to propagate up the chain. And if this is python 2.x we should be using `izip` not `zip`, and so on. But is any of this really relevant for a piece of throwaway code like this?